# Box File Actions Callbacks

Tags: box-api

Was trying to explore file actions.
Particularly what is the function of the preliminary callback and final callback and what are the expected return values.

However the documentation page is missing:
http://developers.box.com/BoxPlatformFileActions

Answer (score 1):

try the documentation at http://developers.box.net/w/page/12923960/BoxPlatformFileActions

Comment: Are these the most up to date docs on file actions?  There is no mention of file actions anywhere in the v2 docs.  Tx.

Comment: File-actions have not been moved to V2 yet.  They are on the short list to be updated soon.